# Use multiple dropdown menus in table as select list

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

so i have a users table, and i wanna add a column to the table where i can get to change the status of the user to active/inactive using bootstrap dropdown menu. here is the code for the tables:

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">1</th>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Active
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Active</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Inactive</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">2</th>
    <td>Jacob</td>
    <td>Thornton</td>
    <td>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Active
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Active</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Inactive</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">3</th>
    <td>Larry</td>
    <td>the Bird</td>
    <td>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Active
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Active</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Inactive</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

i added a JQuery snippet at the end. what this snippet does is changing the `dropdown-menu` label based on the clicked `dropdown-item`.

```
$(function(){
   $(".dropdown-menu").on('click', 'a', function(){
   $(".btn:first-child").text($(this).text());
   $(".btn:first-child").val($(this).text());
   });
});
```

when i change one record's status all other records are effected with that change. i tried using functions like `.find()` and `.siblings()` and even taking off the `id="dropdownMenuButton"` but couldn't fix it. could someone help me get around this issue.

Comment: First off, IDs should be unique. You should not nave multiple elements with the same ID.  That's what classes are for.  Are you trying to set the button text based on what is clicked?

Comment: i did try to take the IDs off.. did nothing, yes, indeed, i am trying to set the button label based on what is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't understand how the jQuery snippet works. It should be:

```
$(function(){
   $(".dropdown-menu").on('click', 'a', function(){
       $(this).parents('.dropdown').find('button').text($(this).text());
   });
});
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/SkKl0OPReI

Comment: thank you so much @ZimSystem . i had something similar to your snippet but i was looking for `siblings` instead and i took off the `"a"` but couldn't make it. thanks again.

Comment: thanks again @ZimSystem for this snippet, i had use it as a reference to help me figuring out many other issues. however i have this one that i could not fix, see the snippet you wrote in this answer works fine if the data was loaded as elements of the html page, but that was a hard code, the table rows will be requested by ajax so this snippet is not working after the data is loaded. what i am trying to do is using `.delegate()` to solve this issue. can you please upgrade this snippet to use `.delegate()` ?

Comment: here is complete issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49083394/jquery-delegate-function-is-half-working