# jquery delegate function is half-working

Tags: jquery, ajax

in a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48977930/use-multiple-dropdown-menus-in-table-as-select-list) i had a problem useing multiple dropdown menus in table as select list and it was solved, thanks to [ZimSystem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171456/zimsystem) with the following snippet:

```
$(function(){
   $(".dropdown-menu").on('click', 'a', function(){
       $(this).parents('.dropdown').find('button').text($(this).text());
   });
});
```

this snippet works fine if the table was created manually, in my project the `tbody`'s `tr` records are being requested using ajax, in short, they will be added after the html page is loaded. which makes the previous snippet don't work. to solve this problem i am using jQuery `$('#myRecords').delegate()`.
here is what i have, the first `log` statement is logging to the console but the second one is not. does anybody knows why this behavior is occurring?

**my snippet**

```
$('#myRecords').delegate(".dropdown-menu", "click", function(event){
  // $(this) = '.dropdown-menu'
  console.log($(this));
  $(this).on('click', 'a', function(){
    // $(this) = 'a'
    console.log($(this));
     $(this).parents('.dropdown').find('button').text($(this).text());
  });
```

**the table**

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id='myRecords'>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">1</th>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Active
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Active</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Inactive</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">2</th>
    <td>Jacob</td>
    <td>Thornton</td>
    <td>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Active
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Active</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Inactive</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">3</th>
    <td>Larry</td>
    <td>the Bird</td>
    <td>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Active
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Active</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Inactive</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: jquery delegate is deprecated. Read more about it and how to replace it here http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: indeed i did, thank you @MateuszJuruś

Comment: You should use `.on` instead of delegate.

Comment: sure will do, i am keeping that in mind. for now i just like how effective it could be. thanks again @ZimSystem , BTW, love your [website](http://iatek.com/)

Comment: i have a question about your website @ZimSystem . is it an open source? I like the information architecture and the simplicity of design that the [iatek](http://iatek.com/) has, and it would be my pleasure to use it to build my portfolio.

Answer (score 0):

and i solved it !, hope it will help other people as well.

```
$('#myRecords').delegate(".dropdown-menu", "click", function(event){
  var status = event.target.text;
  $(this).prev('button').text(status);
});
```